# Open Microsoft Outlook from winforms C# (.net 3.5) application in reply mode

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I open outlook from my Winfoms application. I want to open outlook in reply mode. How can I do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

so you want to open outlook and have it ready to send an email to a prefered receiver.

the quick and dirty fix i think is to have a hidden webbrower in your program and let the browser navigate to `mailto:mail@mail.com?subject=somekindsubject` 
which will open the default email client on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:youremailaddress@whatever.com");
```

The `mailto` can be used with a lot of parameters

Check out the parameters here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(VS.85).aspx

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt

Eg (Taken from MSDN)

```
mailto:user@example.com?subject=MessageTitle&body=MessageContent
```

**UPDATE:** 
Attachments i think are not supported due to security reasons and I strongly agree with it as well.

However Outlook 2003 seems to be accepting the parameter "attachments" according to someone who has posted in MSDN.

```
string email = "mailto:name@domain.com?attachments=\"\"C:\\file.txt\"\"";       

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(email);
```

This is the best i could do and i cannot test it as I do not have Outlook 2003. But even if it works in Outlook 2003, i strongly urge you not to use the attachment parameter as it may not be supported by different programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:mail@address.com?subject=Sample subject");
```

Which will open the default email application filling in the to and subject fields. You can find more options [here](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html).

Edit: this takes a bit of time on my system, so make sure that if your user has a slower computer they'll know what's going on. Also, you should handle the case when they don't have Outlook or another mail program installed if it's a possibility.